# Add a radio div dynamically angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('sampleapp', []);
    app.controller('samplecontroller', ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.itemsToPush=[{amount:'',percentage:''}];
      $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.itemsToPush.push({
                amount:'',
                percentage:''
            })

      };
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="sampleapp" ng-controller="samplecontroller">


  <div class="test" ng-repeat="items in itemsToPush">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="amount" value="amount" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Amount
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <input type="radio" name="percentage" value="percentage" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Percentage
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">Go!</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hi. I am working in angularjs. I have a div which contains two radio buttons(only one can be selected). I have a button called Go.On click Go i need to dynamically add the Radio div.The problem i am facing is when the div gets added,i am able to select only one radio from both(original and replicated) the divs.I need to select one radio button from each div. Thanks in advance.
    Here's https://plnkr.co/edit/cLemG02uFyQupG7h74WM?p=preview

Comment: you need to give unique name to each input radio button like:  <input type="radio" name="amount_{{$index}}" value="amount" ng-model="items.amount">  same as for percentage.

Comment: @Jenny Thanks a lot. It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I am understanding this correctly. Correct me if I am wrong.

You want each row to have two options.
1. Amount 
2. Percentage
Of these only one can be selected.

To achieve this you need to have the same **name** attribute for both radio buttons.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="reductionType" value="amount" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Amount
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="radio" name="reductionType" value="percentage" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Percentage
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
</div>
```

Now based on the item selected you will have either **amount** or **percentage** in the **items.amount** binding.

If you want multiple rows of this then you should use different names for each row. For this the $index variable would be useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
      <script>
         var app = angular.module('sampleapp', []);
         app.controller('samplecontroller', ["$scope", function($scope) {
           $scope.itemsToPush=[{amount:'',percentage:''}];
           $scope.myFunction = function() {
             $scope.itemsToPush.push({
                     amount:'',
                     percentage:''
                })
           };
         }]);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="sampleapp" ng-controller="samplecontroller">
      <div class="test" ng-repeat="items in itemsToPush">
         <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="reductionType_{{$index}}" value="amount{{" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Amount
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <input type="radio" name="reductionType_{{$index}}" value="percentage" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Percentage
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">Go!</button>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The **reductionType_{{$index}}** creates a new radio button group for each iteration hence making only one clickable. (generates reductionType_0, reductionType_1 and so on)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="test" ng-repeat="items in itemsToPush">
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="reduction{{[$index]}}" value="amount" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Amount
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionAmount" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="radio" name="reduction{{[$index]}}" value="percentage" ng-model="items.amount"> Reduction Percentage
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" name="reductiontext" value="" ng-model="items.reductionPercentage" style="width: 80px;">
  </label>
</div>
```

you need to make same names of checkbox of one and add `{{[%index]}}`,so on every increment each div has its own names of checkboxes